# Secure Restful Spring boot application

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, restful-authentication

I have developed a RESTful web service using Spring Boot. Once a URL is entered, a JSON resource is returned. The server side is not perfectly [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) conformed but it works.

Now I want to secure the RESTful service with simple HTTP basic authentication. Simply put, if a client send a HTTP `GET` in order to access

```
http://mycompany.com/restful/xyz
```

it will receive a HTTP unauthenticated error, unless the request is configured with proper `Authorization basic XXXXXXXX`. The xxxxxx is the encrypted form of *user:pwd*

I wanted to do it with Spring Security. After some googling I might need to create some class like:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     ....
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      ....
    }
}
```

There are two things I need to understand:

1. Most Spring Security sample I found were somehow related to web application using Spring MVC, but I am sure that it can be used in a scenario as shown above - a standalone web service (in a Tomcat all right, but not a web app);
2. Can anyone show some code snippet in the two methods above that work to the effect that only certain user/pwd is allowed to pass the filter to the resource,

   ```
   http://mycompany.com/restful/xyz
   ```

   otherwise a HTTP authentication error code is returned.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/restful/**").hasRole("ROLE_USER").and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("john").password("mypass").roles("ROLE_USER");
    }
}
```